# Form add new line on enter, set up for sql

Tags: php, javascript, sql, forms, newline

There are a lot of little pieces of information on this subject, and maybe I'm just not looking in the right spot. But I'd like to put it all together in one place. Start to finish.

I'm trying to make a form pretty much like the one I'm using right now on stack overflow. There is a `textarea`, when someone hits enter, it does not submit the form, but adds a new line. But it doesn't display `\n` or `<br \>` in the actual text box.

Then the text with all structural integrity needs to be entered into a database and retrieved to an xhtml page.

I've hear of using javascript. I've heard of the `nl2br` function. They all seem to be pieces to the puzzle, but I can't find the big picture.

Does anyone have a sample script of start to finish how they would accomplish this?

Thank you very much for your help! I hope others can use this too who are having difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a regular `<textarea>`, and save its raw text to the database.  (making sure to use parameters to prevent SQL injection)

Then, when you want to display the text, use `<pre>` or `nl2br()` to ensure that the newlines are displayed by the browser.

Comment: But how will the php know where to put the line breaks if there isn't some indicator on the database side

Comment: but there is an 'indicator' `\n` you cant see it, but it will be there. Unless you did something crazy like strip them before they go in to the db

Comment: oh....That answers a lot of questions! Now do you know how to make enter not submit the form? Cause I can't test it until I figure that part out too.

I want enter to insert the `\n`. But regardless of if i hit enter or shift enter. The form is submitted.

Comment: your best bet is to let enter do its thing in the text area - not submit the forum, but add an event listener to the textarea for `(keyCode == 13 and shiftKey == true)`  having enter do something other than insert newlines (which could be \n or \r\n depending on the OS) is a bad idea, since it goes against what people would expect the behavior to be.  If you really do want enter to submit, add the same event listener as before (except dont have `shiftKey` as part of the equation), and call `form.submit()`, where `form` is a javascript variable referencing your HTML form element.